# Get the employee name whose's salary is minimun with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a query which show the Out of the employees, who makes the MINIMUM money?

```
Emp_Table 

EmpName   | Salary  | Gender
```

With the right query, the result should be 1 (employee) with the minimum salary

I tried with the following query

```
SELECT MIN(SALARY)
FROM Emp_Table
```

I don't know how can we display employee name as we have to set query on the basis of salary I'm learning the concept and googled it but didn't get a satisfactory answer
Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint : use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]?  Surely it's not *both*.

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you top 1 employee name and his/her salary which is equal to the minimum salary amongst all.

(Remove `TOP 1` if you want all of them.)

```
SELECT TOP 1 EmpName, Salary
FROM Emp_Table
WHERE Salary = (SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM Emp_Table);
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by with top 1

For mssql

```
 SELECT top 1 *
FROM Emp_Table 
order by  Salary asc
```

For mysql

```
SELECT *
    FROM Emp_Table 
    order by  Salary asc
    limit 1
```

Comment: Finally, you have updated it you should realize that early in last 3hours because we should have some responsibility to post at least working code. And I salute to you voters for your votes in blind.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple records having the same minimum `salary` value, then you can use the following query. It works for both `SQL Server` and `MySql`.

**Query**

```
select * from Emp_Table
where salary = (
    select min(salary) from Emp_Table
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

--MySQL

```
  SELECT E1.Employee_name
    FROM Employee_table E1
   WHERE E1.Salary = ( SELECT MIN(E2.Salary)
                       FROM Employee_table E2)
ORDER BY E1.Employee_name
   LIMIT 1
```

--Oracle

```
  SELECT E1.Employee_name
    FROM Employee_table E1
   WHERE E1.Salary = ( SELECT MIN(E2.Salary)
                       FROM Employee_table E2)
ORDER BY E1.Employee_name
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```